# literal_binds=True doesn't work for Date inside @compiles decorated function but works outside of it?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, orm

So, I'll just drop some example code:

```
from datetime import date

from sqlalchemy import select, cast
from sqlalchemy.types import Date
from sqlalchemy.sql import Selectable
from sqlalchemy.schema import DDLElement
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles

engine = ... # get my Redshift dialect engine


class CreateView(DDLElement):
    def __init__(self, name: str, selectable: Selectable, materialized: bool = False, replace: bool = False):
        self.name = name
        self.selectable = selectable
        self.materialized = materialized
        self.replace = replace


@compiles(CreateView)
def compile_create_view(element, compiler, **kw):
    return ' '.join(
        token
        for token in [
            "CREATE",
            "OR REPLACE" if element.replace else None,
            "MATERIALIZED" if element.materialized else None,
            "VIEW",
            compiler.dialect.identifier_preparer.quote(element.name),
            "AS",
            compiler.sql_compiler.process(element.selectable, literal_binds=True),
        ]
        if token is not None
    )
```

Given the above definition for a custom `CreateView` DDL statement, we can easily render an example, like so:

```
create_view = CreateView(
    name='testing',
    selectable=select(cast(date(2000, 1, 1), Date)),
    replace=True,
)

print(create_view.compile(compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True}))

# CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "testing" AS SELECT CAST('2000-01-01' AS DATE) AS anon_1
```

So far so good. Only when I try to actually execute it I get the following error:

```
with engine.connect() as con:
    con.execute(create_view)

# NotImplementedError: Don't know how to literal-quote value datetime.date(2000, 1, 1)
```

Running this through a debugger it looks like when I just compile it the compiler that gets passed to my `compile_create_view()` function has access to a `StrSqlCompiler` as its `.sql_compiler` attribute, whereas when executing it what gets passed is a `RedshiftCompiler`.

So I guess my question is, how should I go about fixing this? Can I somehow 'teach' the `RedshiftCompiler` how to handle incoming Date literals (as either date objects or strings), just like the `StrSqlCompiler` can already do? Or should I be somehow constructing a new `StrSqlCompiler` inside my `compile_create_view()` function instead and using that? Or something else entirely?

I don't even know what the correct approach is, so I'm kinda wary of making my question too specific, cause I want to avoid the xy-problem. Thanks in advance.